# HOW TO GET THE Postion in the type of int in list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

i am using a listview in my application and want the postion of the item clicked in the listview

here i have this code in my

**main.java**

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // selected item 
         //here i want to get the index/ postion of the selected item in the listview
      }
    });
```

thanks

Comment: int position OnItemClickListener() gives you the position on which click has occured

Comment: but to get the postion in int form can you give me a example ..? @pramod yadav

Comment: yes it will give you position as int what you want to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

int position will return position which you click.

in above link its mention

**position  The position of the view in the adapter**

Hope it will help you.

Let me know if need any help from my side on same.

Comment: your welcome and if need any help anytime please write me down.

Answer (score 3):

When you set OnItemClickListener and call onItemClick function it give u formal parameter.
actually u have your answer in your question.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id)
```

this int position is list item position.
u can make switch for further functionality .

Answer (score 1):

The position is already passed along to you as an int, `int position`.

Answer (score 1):

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ID", ""+id); // here I am using the id 
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        chooseOptions(id);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this , **int position is the index of your list value** that is clicked.

```
       JobList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int position, long id) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "hi my position is: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
  });
```

If you are using a List to populate the ListView in your onItemClick() method.

string value=  list.get(position);

Happy Coding